# Does thenRunAsync (as opposed to thenRun) make any difference if chained after a runAsync call?

Tags: java, java-8, completable-future

In the following code, does it make any difference to call *thenRunAsync*? Should I just call *thenRun* instead?

```
CompletableFuture.runAsync(this::doWork , executorService)
     .thenRunAsync(this::handleSuccess);
```

Elaborating in response to the comments: If I were to use this code instead,

```
CompletableFuture.runAsync(this::doWork , executorService)
     .thenRun(this::handleSuccess);
```

would it behave any differently?

In both cases, the behavior is non-blocking, and the second task won't run until the first completes, as far as I understand it, anyhow.

Comment: Well the difference is that `handleSuccess` will be invoked asynchronously when `doWork` has finished normally. I'm not sure what kind of answer you're looking for.

Comment: @Tunaki: I suppose, the question is aiming at the fact that the action supplied to `thenRun` is executed asynchronously as well (in respect to the thread invoking `thenRun`), if the previous stage hasn’t completed by the time of the `thenRun` invocation. But apparently, there are even more differences than the question is aiming at…

Answer (score 18, accepted):

The method `thenRun` allows the execution of the `Runnable` directly in the caller’s thread, if the `CompletableFuture` has already completed. Since even in a direct invocation chain like `CompletableFuture.runAsync(…).thenRun(…);` there’s the possibility that the asynchronous task has already completed by the time `thenRun` is invoked, there’s the possibility that the dependent action is executed in the caller’s thread, unlike `thenRunAsync` which will always use the default (or provided) executor.

So in one sentence, yes, it makes a difference.

---

By the way, using `thenRunAsync` (the single argument version) will not execute the action using the `Executor` supplied to the initial factory call, but the default `Executor`.

You can easily compare the different behaviors:

```
public static void main(String[] args) {
    ExecutorService e=Executors.newSingleThreadExecutor(r -> new Thread(r, "sole thread"));
    CompletableFuture<?> f=CompletableFuture.runAsync(()->{}, e);
    f.join();
    f.thenRun(()->System.out.println("thenRun:\t"+Thread.currentThread()));
    f.thenRunAsync(()->System.out.println("thenRunAsync:\t"+Thread.currentThread()));
    f.thenRunAsync(()->System.out.println("thenRunAsync+e:\t"+Thread.currentThread()), e);
    e.shutdown();
}
```

will print

```
thenRun:        Thread[main,5,main]
thenRunAsync:   Thread[ForkJoinPool.commonPool-worker-1,5,main]
thenRunAsync+e: Thread[sole thread,5,main]
```

whereas

```
public static void main(String[] args) {
   ExecutorService e=Executors.newSingleThreadExecutor(r -> new Thread(r, "sole thread"));
   CompletableFuture<?>f=CompletableFuture.runAsync(()->LockSupport.parkNanos((int)1e9),e);
   f.thenRun(()->System.out.println("thenRun:\t"+Thread.currentThread()));
   f.thenRunAsync(()->System.out.println("thenRunAsync:\t"+Thread.currentThread()));
   f.thenRunAsync(()->System.out.println("thenRunAsync+e:\t"+Thread.currentThread()), e);
   LockSupport.parkNanos((int)2e9);
   e.shutdown();
}
```

will print

```
thenRun:        Thread[sole thread,5,main]
thenRunAsync:   Thread[ForkJoinPool.commonPool-worker-1,5,main]
thenRunAsync+e: Thread[sole thread,5,main]
```

So `thenRun` may execute the action in either, the caller’s thread or the `Executor`’s thread whereas the single-argument `thenRunAsync` will always use the Fork/Join pool and only the two argument `thenRunAsync` will always use the provided executor.

Comment: The javadoc for CompletableFuture says that 


"Actions supplied for dependent completions of non-async methods may be performed by the thread that completes the current CompletableFuture, or by any other caller of a completion method."

If 'completion method' are the methods [join, complete, completeExceptionally, cancel] (is this correct?) then there is no issue calling CompletableFuture.thenRunAsync(...).thenRun(...), since a completion method is not called.

Comment: @kantianethics it’s a flaw of the documentation to use that term “completion method” without defining it, but as the code examples of this answer demonstrate, `thenRun` *is* such a completion method. In fact any of these method for chaining a dependent action is such a completion method which may execution dependent actions, not restricted to the one you’re just chaining. In other words, if thread A chains action *a* at the same time, thread B chains action *b*, it would even be possible that A performs *b* and B performs *a*. These methods without “…Async” provide the least control.

Comment: Yes you are right. I figured `join` was needed for `thenRun` to execute on the caller thread (it is not).