# Why CompletableFuture did not execute in sequence?

Tags: java, completable-future

My goal is to understand how CompletableFuture works.

My expected result: If I do `CompletableFuture.runAsync().thenRun().thenRunAsync()`. The thread will be executed in sequence `runAsync() -> thenRun() -> thenRunAsync()`.

My actual result: The sequence is race condition. Sometimes:

1. `runAsync` -> `thenRunAsync+e` -> ...
2. `runAsync` -> `thenRun` -> ...

[Reference from SO](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/36462774/does-thenrunasync-as-opposed-to-thenrun-make-any-difference-if-chained-after-a)

```
public class RunExample5 {
  public static void main(String[] args) {
    ExecutorService e = Executors.newSingleThreadExecutor(r -> new Thread(r, "sole thread"));
    CompletableFuture<?> f = CompletableFuture.runAsync(() -> {
              System.out.println("runAsync:\t" + Thread.currentThread());
              LockSupport.parkNanos((int) 1e9);
            }, e);
    f.thenRun(() -> System.out.println("thenRun:\t" + Thread.currentThread()));
    f.thenRunAsync(() -> System.out.println("thenRunAsync:\t" + Thread.currentThread()));
    f.thenRunAsync(() -> System.out.println("thenRunAsync+e:\t" + Thread.currentThread()),
            e);
    LockSupport.parkNanos((int) 2e9);
    e.shutdown();
  }
}
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You need

```
f.thenRun(() -> System.out.println("thenRun:\t" + Thread.currentThread()))
    .thenRunAsync(() -> System.out.println("thenRunAsync:\t" + Thread.currentThread()))
    .thenRunAsync(() -> System.out.println("thenRunAsync+e:\t" + Thread.currentThread()), e);
```

The interface to `CompletableFuture` doesn't work quite the way you're imagining. `f` itself doesn't keep track of every call to `thenRun` or `thenRunAsync` and run them in order; instead, it treats everything from `thenRun` or `thenRunAsync` as simultaneously runnable as soon as the main work completes. If you want to chain more complicated sequences of work, you need to use the return value of `thenRun` or `thenRunAsync` -- a `CompletionStage` object -- and call `thenRunAsync` on *that*.